# File does not begin with '%PDF-'

Tags: asp.net, pdf, export

I am exporting the HTML Content to PDF.

```
    System.IO.StringWriter sWriter = new System.IO.StringWriter();

    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(sWriter);

    Response.Buffer = true;
    FormId.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    // Added appropriate headers
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=XXX.pdf");
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", htmlWriter.ToString().Length.ToString());
    Response.Output.Write(sWriter.ToString());

    Response.Flush();
    Response.Close();
```

FormId is my Div past of the content..

I am getting the error as "File does not begin with '%PDF-'"

I have included Response.clear(); The output is not coming

Comment: Does sWriter actually give you a valid PDF file? Check its first four bytes.

Answer (score 3):

You're rendering out the html (div as you said) before the pdf in the output stream, so the two are combined. That's causing any app looking at the output to interpret it as a corrupted file. I'd try removing the first two lines:

```
Response.Buffer = true;
FormId.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
```

If that doesn't solve the issue, add a Response.Clear() call before everything.

This is all assuming sWriter contains the PDF at the beginning of this code block -- if not, a little more context might be helpful.

Some advice: if at all possible, move this out of the page to a .ashx or other IHttpHandler.

Comment: Good advice, the overhead for an http handler is much lower than for a page handler.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue while writing some HTML content to PDF.

I finally found that invalid HTML content causes this issue.

For example, `<ul>` tag without closing tag `</ul>`.

Once I put in the proper closing tags, it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Do a Response.Clear() before starting to stream your output.